# What is the panel that appears after Scale operation and what is the command to display it independently?

Tags: scale

After selecting a face and scaling it with an <kbd>S</kbd> operation, a panel appears on the lower left hand side:

[image]

The panel is labelled Resize and shows the results of the scaling operation (in this case a scale value of 1.1 for all three axes).

What is this panel and how can I display it on command?

Comment: The panel is called "Redo Last": https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/undo_redo.html

Comment: @Haunt_House Thank you so much.  Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The panel is called "Redo Last"

It's always in the tool shelf <kbd>T</kbd> of the 3D-Editor or accessible as a popup with <kbd>F6</kbd>.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/undo_redo.html

Comment: Also note that it depends on *Global Undo* option in the User Preference and will be available if it's enabled and amount of steps is set to > than 0

Answer (score 3):

You can display the floating window version by pressing F6 after the Scaling operation.

So, something like S -> ENTER -> F6

Edit to add link to docs. - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/basics.html?highlight=scale#scale

Comment: Yes, this works thanks.  Do you know which menu system the fixed panel is part of?

Comment: Perhaps this page helps? - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/basics.html?highlight=scale#scale